# Xdebug Install Fails on M1 Mac

Tags: php, xdebug, apple-m1

Xdebug will not install for me on my M1 Mac.

PHP installed via homebrew.

Output:

```
❯ file `which php`
/opt/homebrew/bin/php: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
```

```
❯ php --version
PHP 8.2.0 (cli) (built: Dec  9 2022 16:19:06) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.2.0, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

I have tried installing via pecl two ways:

`arch -arm64 pecl install xdebug`
`sudo pecl install xdebug`

Both result in errors, last 4 lines of which are:

```
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-thatryanKQAoHZ/xdebug-3.2.1':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/configure --with-php-config=/opt/homebrew/opt/php/bin/php-config' failed
```

[Full Log Output Gist](https://gist.github.com/thatryan/7a6b1e3f866f78522d1db89ca133ae4f)

I am also unsure of where that **config.log** file exists...

Comment: "See `config.log' for more details"

Comment: Yeah I mentioned that in the post, I cannot find where that log file exists, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out, apparently I hade never installed compilers on this machine wow. So running `xcode-select --install` to get gcc installed allowed it to complete.